# Should I use a method that returns a value and then print the return value in main or just include a print statement in the method?

Tags: java

So, say I have a method that does a calculation and I want to print the result. Is it preferrable to make the method return an integer value like:

```
public int addTwoNumbers(){
     .........
     return result;
```

}

And then I could print it using a sysout statement in the main method or should i just put a print out statement inside the the method and make it a return type of void.

```
public void addTwoNumbers(){
        ...........
        System.out.println(result);
```

}

Comment: I agree with the questioner here. https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/3747

Comment: If you were strictly logical, you would name the second function `printAddTwoNumbers`. This already could solve your problem.

Comment: Questions about best practices are better suited to [programmers.se].

Answer (score 2):

This is a topic of great importance and lengthy theories which you can read about. Look for "Clean Code" (originally a book by Robert Martin).

However, a short practical answer would be - return the value. If a function is supposed to "Add Two Numbers" it should make this sum available to the caller, and it *shouldn't* do printing.

That will allow (for example...) to add 3 numbers, by making 2 calls to `AddTwoNumbers`.

Answer (score 2):

Function's name should describe what it does. In your case `addTwoNumbers` should just add two numbers and nothing more. Rule of thumb: functions should do only one thing (I recommend you to read great book "Clean code"). In the second case more appropriate name would be `printSumOfNumbers`.  Moreover the first method is slightly more universal because you can use the reuslt in any way you want in the future, not only print it to the console.